How to have only side navbar display as index page for Quarto website
I'm working on a simple Quarto project website that's just for storing a collection of typst pdfs in organized sections. The side navbar Quarto generates is everything I need for the homepage. Is there any way to have Quarto not display anything of the main body etc. from index.qmd and just render the side navbar as the whole page?

In case anyone else wants to do something similar in the future, I added some css to styles.css and added it to the css: option in _quarto.yaml to 1) make the sidebar 100% of the screen, 2) prevent the collapse transition, and 3) remove the collapse button
#quarto-sidebar {
  width: 100dvw !important;
  overflow: visible !important;
}

#quarto-sidebar.collapse {
    display: block !important;
    height: auto !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
    transition: none !important;
}

.quarto-btn-toggle {
    display: none !important;
}

